# Botón pantalla completa html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo implementar un botón que inicie la pantalla completa en una `app` de chrome a base de html y javascript? .

He intentado con `state: 'fullscreen'` y métodos `window.fullScreen();` y parecidos pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 3):

las **APIs** nuevas de **Javascript** vinieron a ayudar mucho, aunque todavia no son del todo conocidas.

Una muy simple y efectiva es la que nos permite activar la pantalla completa en el navegador directamente desde un botón en nuestro sitio.

```js
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
// Lanza en pantalla completa en navegadores que lo soporten
 function cancelFullScreen() {
     if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
         document.cancelFullScreen();
     } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
         document.mozCancelFullScreen();
     } else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
         document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
     }
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="launchFullScreen(document.documentElement);"> Entrar en pantalla completa </button>
<button onclick="cancelFullScreen();"> Salir de pantalla completa </button>
```

El método `requestFullScreen` está aún prefijado en los navegadores, por eso, hay buscarlo un poco, para que nuestra web funcione bien en **cualquier browser.**

Simplemente llama al request del método en el elemento que quieres en pantalla completa, y la ventana cambiará a pantalla completa.

Comment: Hola @JohnnyPachecp. Para que se usa el `element` y que diferencia hay en que se use con u otro element?

Comment: @Theia `document.documentElement` devuelve un `HTMLElement` que hace referencia al `DOM`, es decir que ahora puedes tratar a todo el documento como si se tratase de un elemento normal, por lo que ahora podrás: agregar eventos `document.documentElement.addEventListener(TODO)` , despachar eventos `document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(TODO)` , acceder a sus propiedades `CSS2`, `window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)`, y en general a todas las propiedades del prototipo `HTMLElement` para más información puedes acceder a ellas mediatne `console.log(HTMLElement.prototype)`

Comment: No me funcionó en el snippet ¿Puede ser?

Comment: Lo que dice @Theia es totalmente cierto, gracias por brindar la respuesta... Y no funciona en el snippet por que no lo permite stackoverflow.

Comment: a mi me funciona pero cuando me muevo a otro sitio en la misma pagina se quita la pantalla completa, en cambio cuando lo hago con la tecla f11 no pasa eso, como puedo hacer que se mantenga en pantalla completa?